# Elasticsearch: Retrieving total number of items in a "get most recent" collapse/inner_hits query

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have a set of documents with number (string) and timestamp (date) fields. I built a query to return a list of most recent documents by number values, with per-number counts.

For example, for a dataset like this one

| number | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| test-number-1 | 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z |
| test-number-1 | 2023-01-02T00:00:00.000Z |
| test-number-2 | 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z |
| test-number-3 | 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z |
| test-number-3 | 2023-01-02T00:00:00.000Z |
| test-number-3 | 2023-01-03T00:00:00.000Z |

I would get this information back

| number | timestamp | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test-number-1 | 2023-01-02T00:00:00.000Z | 2 |
| test-number-2 | 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1 |
| test-number-3 | 2023-01-03T00:00:00.000Z | 3 |

Easy enough, this is something that [collapse with inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/collapse-search-results.html) can help with. If I sort by `timestamp` while limiting `size` to 1, I get only most recent documents grouped by `number` back. Sweet.

```
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "number",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "most_recent",
      "_source": [
        "id",
        "timestamp",
        "foo",
        "number"
      ],
      "size": 1,
      "sort": [
        {
          "timestamp": "desc"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### The problem is top level counts

Here is an example truncated, simplified result.

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 6, <=== TOTAL HITS COUNT: 6
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "hits": [ <=== ARRAY SIZE: 3
      {
        "fields": {
          "number": [
            "test-number-1"
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "most_recent": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_source": {
                    "number": "test-number-1",
                    "timestamp": "2023-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
...
        "number": [
          "test-number-2"
        ]
...
        "total": {
          "value": 1,
          }
...
    },
    {
...
        "number": [
          "test-number-3"
        ]
...
        "total": {
          "value": 3,
          }
...
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how the `hits` arrray that contains all the `inner_hits` results has 3 items in it,

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [ <=== ARRAY SIZE: 3
      { ... },
      { ... },
      { ... } 
    ]
  }
}
```

while the total number of hits for the query is showing 6 hits

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 6, <=== TOTAL HITS COUNT: 6
      "relation": "eq"
    }
  }
}
```

### How do I get the real number of hits?

so that it's showing 3 instead of 6 like in an example up above? I want to be able to paginate through the results, so my real query would limit the page size, e.g.

`{ "size": 10, "from": 20 }`.

therefore I cannot rely on the `hits` array size, as in my case it would be limited to 10 items per page.

Comment: The only workaround that I was able to find so far was adding `term_aggregations` to the query and using resulting `buckets` array size as total count value, but I don't like it as it feels like a hack.

`{ ..., "aggs": { "term_aggregations": { "terms": { "field": "number", "size": 10000 } } } }`

Comment: It's not a hack, it's the way to proceed if you need exact count + pagination, since the collapsing only happens on top documents

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `terms` aggregation with the `top_hits` sub-aggregation to achieve what you want and if you want to [paginate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_pagination), I would even throw the `composite` aggregation into the mix:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "pages": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "number": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "number"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": [
             "id",
             "timestamp",
             "foo",
             "number"
            ],
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": "desc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The ES documentation states that `top_hits` should not be used as a top-level aggregation and one should [use the collapse parameter instead](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) - that's why I went for `collapse` in my query. I tried your suggestion and the total numbers for `hits` still does not take into consideration the fact that documents are being aggregated - it's the # of documents in total, not the size of the non-paginated bucket.

Comment: Two things: 1) in my answer top_hits is not at top level, but as a sub-aggregation for terms buckets. 2) it's an aggregation query (not a search query), you don't look at the hits part at all (which is why size is specified as 0), you should only care about the `aggregations.pages.buckets` array, where each bucket has the right doc count

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation @val. Is there any reason why `collapse` would be inferior to the `aggs` approach that you suggested? I have an established pagination pattern for search originating queries and I would like to avoid the next token-style pagination approach that the `after_key` is enforcing.

Comment: `collapse` is not inferior but implements something similar to aggs without yielding the same accuracy regarding counts, as you could see, because it's run on top sorted documents only, whereas aggs are run on all documents. Another solution for you, but unsure if your use cases is compatible with it, would be to use a scheduled [`latest` transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-overview.html#latest-transform-overview) (which basically runs the same query) and run your search query against the new index that is created and maintained in the process.

Comment: That search query would be a normal search query where you can use the pagination pattern you're used to